# Launch process in background and retrieve output

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I want to launch an instance of my Flask app in the background so I can run webdriver tests on it. For that I need to catch the output of the `&` command so I can kill the process when the test ends.

I've tried `subprocess.call()`, and `subprocess.check_output()` but I can't catch the process number of the first or background the process with the other. What else can I try?

Comment: Have you looked at [Flask-Testing](https://flask-testing.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#testing-with-liveserver) ?

Comment: Glad that worked for you! done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look at the [Flask-Testing](https://flask-testing.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#testing-with-liveserver) library, which has support for running your flask server so you can do selenium tests against it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use nohup with Popen:

```
from subprocess import Popen, check_call

from os import devnull

p = Popen(["nohup", "python", "test.py"], stdout=open(devnull, "w"))

import time

print(p.pid)
for i in range(3):
    print("In for")
    time.sleep(1)

check_call("ps -ef | grep {} | grep -v grep".format(p.pid), shell=True)
p.terminate()
check_call("ps -ef | grep {} | grep -v grep".format(p.pid), shell=True)
```

test.py:

```
import  time
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Still alive")
```

The output:

```
In [3]: from os import devnull

In [4]: p = Popen(["nohup", "python", "b.py"], stdout=open(devnull, "w"))
nohup: ignoring input and redirecting stderr to stdout
In [5]: print(p.pid)
28332

In [6]: for i in range(3):
   ...:         print("In for")
   ...:         time.sleep(1)
   ...:     
In for
In for
In for

In [7]: check_call("ps -ef | grep {} | grep -v grep".format(p.pid), shell=True)
padraic  28332 28301  1 20:55 pts/8    00:00:00 python test.py 
Out[7]: 0

In [8]: p.terminate()

In [9]: check_call("ps -ef | grep {} | grep -v grep".format(p.pid), shell=True)
padraic  28332 28301  0 20:55 pts/8    00:00:00 [python] <defunct>
Out[9]: 0
```

Comment: Isn't Popen deprecated?

Comment: @ruipacheco, os.Popen, not subprocess.Popen, 99 percent of subprocess uses Popen